# Removing a row in sheet 2 from imported data from sheet 1 in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, row

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPviN.jpg)

Hi all, i need help and i am not a coder. I am trying to achieve the same thing on sheet number 2.

My datas are imported through "=Submission!$b2" from sheet 1

i need help removing rows automatically when a specific cell on column H does not contain the value "Bekreft", i tried both codes shown here with no success.

This is what i added for script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('DATA - Do Not Touch!!!'); // change to your own
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=values.length;i>0;i-=1){
     var lcVal=values[i-1][0].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case
     var index = lcVal.indexOf("vent"); //now you only have to check for      contains "vent"
     if (lcVal.indexOf("vent") > -1){
     s.deleteRow(i)};
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you state you are "not a coder", and the code you pasted will not help you if you are referencing data from another page, I would suggest using a filter function to achieve your goal. You would add the following formula to your second page:

```
  =FILTER(Submission!B:B,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bekreft", Submission!H:H)))
```

If you are looking to have a script go through your static list and delete out values that do not contain "Bekreft" then you can use the following script.

```
  function onEdit() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Add Sheet ID").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();

    var rowsDeleted = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
        var row = values[i];

          //row for condition
          if (row[7].indexOf("Bekreft")) {     
            sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
            rowsDeleted++;
     }
    }
   };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the delete option is actually not a good option as the "status" are updated and once updated the row is deleted and will not reappear...

Comment: However i am trying the filter but not sure how to use it, what are the B:B suppose to be? and H:H? As i do not understand it i cannot use it. Thanks for the help and answer so far.

Comment: B:B refers to the entire column B. It will pull any value in B where the value in column H contains "Bekreft". If you want to pull more rows based off the criteria in column H you can change B:B to A:I for example. I would suggest you read up on the [Filter function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197), but I have also linked a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yw1fg3ZxuedduWkuNGqRjARYOlNgu5mn2Xe2QdylLok/edit?usp=sharing) with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My headache is now gone!

Comment: One last litte thing, if i want to create a sheet with the same function but showing the rows where that specific cell is empty only, how should i proceed?

Comment: For filtering only blanks you would take out SEARCH and ISNUMBER, and the condition portion of your filter would change to `ISBLANK(Submission!H:H)`